# how to add junit testcase for null hashmap

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, collections, mockito

I have below code snippet of hashmap

```
if (defgmap==null){

return Collections.emptylist();
}
```

How can we add junit test case / using mockito object for the same null check .As I am new to this, any leads would be helpful.
What about using assertnull() ?

Comment: Can you explain the question ? According to the snippet, if input is null, it ll return empty list. In that case, you cant use assertNull. You can use assertEquals() and pass empty list as an argument.

Comment: yes..input is null and it returns empty list .Could you please elaborate more? Sorry. I donot have any exp in unit test writing.

Comment: then use assertEquals and pass empty list as an argument

Comment: First we have to declare Map<String,String> nullCheckmap = new HashMap<>(); Then in the @test , shall we add nullChecekmap==null; then assertequals() calling?

Answer (score 2):

The key is what result you expect.

1. Expect the map must be null:

   ```java
   Assert.assertNull("The map should be null", map);
   ```

   If the map is not null, this test should failed.
2. Expect the returned list must be empty:

   ```java
   Assert.assertEquals("The returned list should be empty", Collections.emptyList(), returnedList);
   ```

You can't use Assert.* methods as if-statement.

If you don't know which method to use, here is a generic example:

```java
// condition is a boolean expression or variable
Assert.assertTrue("The condition should be true", condition);
Assert.assertFalse("The condition should be false", condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample is the class name and test is the method name.

```
public List<String> test(List<String> request)
{
    if (request==null){

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return request;
}


@Test
public void test()
{
    List<String> result = sample.test(null);
    Assert.assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(), result);
}
```